# Hbase Cluster down due to the one of the Hadoop HA namenode went unreachable

Tags: hadoop, hbase, failover

I have a HA Hadoop with active and standby namenode and  a HBase setup with master and backup master. Active nameode and Hbase Master runs in the same Physical machine. In the same way, standby namenode and backup hbase master in another machine.

Hadoop version - 2.7.3
Hbase version - 1.2.6

The active namenode machines went to unreachable state to the network issue. During this, Standby namenode takes over as active namenode and there is no problem in the Hadoop cluster

But in the Hbase cluster has been shut down completely with the below exception

```
2018-04-12 06:18:08,016 INFO  [198.176.234.24:16020.activeMasterManager] master.ActiveMasterManager: Deleting ZNode for /hbase/backup-masters/198.176.234.24,16020,1522243404960 from backup master directory
2018-04-12 06:18:08,023 INFO  [198.176.234.24:16020.activeMasterManager] master.ActiveMasterManager: Registered Active Master=198.176.234.24,16020,1522243404960
2018-04-12 06:18:28,149 INFO  [198.176.234.24:16020.activeMasterManager] retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking setSafeMode of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB over /198.176.234.24:9999 after 1 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 720ms.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setSafeMode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1063)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:519)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:971)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$600(HMaster.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$2.run(HMaster.java:1803)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2018-04-12 06:18:48,892 INFO  [198.176.234.24:16020.activeMasterManager] retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking setSafeMode of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB over 198.176.234.56/198.176.234.56:9999 after 2 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 2459ms.
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From 198.176.234.24/198.176.234.24 to 198.176.234.56:9999 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=198.176.234.56/198.176.234.56:9999]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Why the backup Hbase master doesn't take over as Hbase Master? As the Master down, all the region servers went down and makes cluster shutdown

What is the configuration I'm missing here?

Please help